# Problem at comparing dates Bash script to Telegram bot

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that is comparing 2 dates ( one from a file that is stored in the server and the other using `date` command), it was working just fine but after the month ended it cannot compare the 2 dates, here is the code:

```
consult)

                    local FECHA=`curl -s $URL_UPDATE | jq '.result[0].message.text' | awk -F "_" '{print $2}' | tr -d '"'`

                    local DATE=`date "+%d-%m-%y"`

                    if [[ ${FECHA#0} -ge ${DATE#0} ]]; then

                            $SEND"Wrong Date"

                    else

                           $SEND"Right Date"
                 
                    fi
```

PD: The URL_UPDATE variable is just the Telegram API getUpdates url, I take the first date from the user via Telegram after the _ if the user puts any. About $SEND, is the "send_message" function from the Telegram API.

Comment: Lexical comparison of dates in dd-mm-yy format will of course not work like you hope. This is why we use yyyy-mm-dd format (or seconds since the epoch) for anything which needs to be machine-readable.

Comment: @tripleee I was using that format because the file where i am taking the first date from is in that format, i will try with the seconds since epoch, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ -ge ]` compares numbers. But dates of the format `dd-mm-yyyy` are not numbers.

If you use the date format `yyyymmdd` you can compare dates using `-ge`. You can convert the first date using `sed`, which can also do the things you did with `awk` and `tr`.

```
local fecha=$(curl -s "$URL_UPDATE" | jq '.result[0].message.text' |
              sed -En 's/^[^_]*_[^_]*(..)-(..)-(....).*/\3\2\1/p')
local date=$(date +%y%m%d)
if (( fecha >= date )); then
  # do stuff
else
  # do stuff
fi
```

By the way:

- Variables in bash should be written in `lowercase` and *not* in `ALLCAPS`, to avoid accidental collision with special environment variables.
- `$(cmd)` is better than `` `cmd` `` as it can be nested.
- `(( var >= var ))` is easier to write/read than `[[ "$var" -ge "$var" ]]`.
- In your code `$SEND"Wrong Date"` there is probably a space missing between `$SEND` and `"Wrong date"`. Also, instead of storing a command inside the variable `$SEND`, define a function `send() { ... }`.